Creating a singleton terminal struct in C (OSDev)
I am not very knowledgeable about very low-level programming so I wanted to have a pet project to explore it - I am attempting to write something, that would hopefully be considered an OS.
Having written an assembly bootloader, I have proceeded to try to write a kernel in C, here is my code:
//kernel.c
#include "terminal.h"
#include "terminal_backend.h"
void _start(void) {
 Terminal* terminal = getTerminalInstance();
 T_clearScreen(terminal);
 for (;;) {}
 ...
}

//terminal.h
#pragma once
#include <stdint.h>

struct Terminal;
typedef struct Terminal Terminal;
//TBptr = Terminal backend function pointer
typedef void (*TBptr_moveCursor)(Terminal* t, uint16_t x, uint16_t y);
typedef void (*TBptr_getCursorPosition)(Terminal* t, uint16_t* x, uint16_t* y);
typedef void (*TBptr_clearScreen)(Terminal* t);
typedef void (*TBptr_putCharacter)(Terminal* t, uint32_t ch);
typedef void (*TBptr_getSize)(Terminal* t, uint16_t *w, uint16_t *h);

struct Terminal
{
        TBptr_moveCursor TF_moveCursor;
        TBptr_getCursorPosition TF_getCursorPosition;
        TBptr_clearScreen TF_clearScreen;
        TBptr_putCharacter TF_putCharacter;
        TBptr_getSize TF_getSize;
        void* backend_data;
};
...

//fragment of terminal.c
...
void T_clearScreen(Terminal* terminal)
{
        terminal->TF_clearScreen(terminal);
}
...

//fragment of terminal_backend.c
static void primitiveClearScreen(Terminal* terminal)
{
        for (;;) {}
        ...
}
...
static Terminal functionTable = {
        .TF_moveCursor = primitiveMoveCursor,
        .TF_getCursorPosition = primitiveGetCursorPosition,
        .TF_clearScreen = primitiveClearScreen,
        .TF_putCharacter = primitivePutCharacter,
        .TF_getSize = primitiveGetSize
};
  
Terminal* getTerminalInstance(void)
{                                                                                                                                  
        return &functionTable;                                                         
} 

The issue is that T_clearScreen(Terminal* terminal) gets called but the infinite loop in primitiveClearScreen(Terminal* terminal) does not get executed (By that I mean processor triple faults). It seems to me that the struct didn't get properly configured and so couldn't make the proper call to the function adresses. Compiler does not complain about the code. What I expected to happen is that this code should produce statically allocated struct Terminal with pointers to functions that I have implemented in terminal_backend.c and by calling getTerminalInstance() we get the singleton instance adress and can now call the T_clearScreen(terminal).
This also might be caused by process I did to the kernel and other files, but I am hoping that it is not the problem and it's much simpler. I am still going to describe it in case that is.
The process of getting the C code into the floppy.bin (my virtual floppy) is that I paste the LOAD headers from ELF format into the floppy. Then I tell the bootloader to paste the binary into the proper locations + 0x40000 offset (to align with tutorial I am following). I suppose it could mess with addresses, so I consider it as a possible cause. The "proper locations" are in range from 0x0000 to 0x2000 - which I thought as too low, which is also a reason for including the offset.
I use QEMU, here is command that I use to run the floppy: 
qemu-system-x86_64 -fda floppy.bin -cpu core2duo

Are you sure your bootloader loads all of itself and the kernel (both code and data)? Side note: A boot and kernel is an ambitious project for someone not well versed in C and assembly. We'd probably need to see your bootloader code and kernel startup code (that sets protected mode). Before you add the complexity of a terminal emulator [that you have], can you prove the kernel can stuff text into the text frame buffer and it displays on the screen. Also, where are you going to output your debug printf calls to (e.g. UART is the usual)?

@CraigEstey - Thank you for your response! I managed to fix the issue. The DATA wasn't loaded correctly which was caused by my offseting of LOADs adresses from ELF in my bootloader. It turned out that it wasn't needed and it broke something.

@CraigEstey
I am not really sure what I am going to do with debug printf since I am following a tutorial for now. There is the link (Unfortunately it's in Polish)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxh-Ebd4uP0&t=13084s
I am looking forward to explore everything and since my experience is low I prefer to take things step by step. As far as I know the next function to be implemented is T_printf and it displays text by loading it into text frame buffer - I think you meant something diffrent with debug print and I thought about something like this so probably I will implement it when well informed

@CraigEstey
The kernel can stuff text into the frame buffer. I have even managed to run it on a real machine. Here is my code that displays "Hello World":
https://github.com/Tysek64/papos/tree/KernelNo1
The issue was in stage2 - the offset adding in .ph_loop (program header walkthrough loop) broke the addressing and commenting it out fixed my issue.  I also made call to this address so after .ph_loop I had to comment out the offset (The offset was 0x3ff000).
This is a college project to basically have fun with low level and explore a bit - nothing too serious.
